# a filtered index to support a query - is it possible to consider nulls?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, index-tuning, filtered-index

I have been dealing with this query:

```
SELECT @amount = sum(accountAmount)  
FROM dbo.accountTransaction  
WHERE invoiceID = @invoiceID  
 AND (notCountedInTotal = 0 OR notCountedInTotal IS NULL)
```

ans as I have had [good experiences](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74122/22336) [with filtered indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90975/filtered-index-is-not-selected-once-an-identical-non-filtered-index-is-made?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I can create this one:

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX F_INVOICEID  ON dbo.accountTransaction (  INVOICEID  )  INCLUDE ( accountAmount)  
 where (notCountedInTotal is null)
```

But that would not solve my query problem above.
So I would like to have the following filtered index:

```
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX F_INVOICEID  ON dbo.accountTransaction (  INVOICEID  )  INCLUDE ( accountAmount)  
 WHERE (notCountedInTotal IN (null,0))
```

> Msg 10620, Level 16, State 1, Line 38 Filtered index 'F_INVOICEID'
>   cannot be created on table 'dbo.accountTransaction' because the filter
>   expression contains a comparison with a literal NULL value. Rewrite
>   the comparison to use the IS [NOT] NULL comparison operator to test
>   for NULL values.

is it at all possible?

would it be worth creating a computed column, persisted, that would put the zeros and nulls together and create the index on that?

[is there a work around for when you want to put an OR inside a filtered index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116378/is-there-a-work-around-for-when-you-want-to-put-an-or-inside-a-filtered-index?rq=1)

would I not get into the same issue as below?

[Unable to create a Filtered Index on a Computed Column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116347/unable-to-create-a-filtered-index-on-a-computed-column?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: An index on `(invoiceid, notCountedInTotal) INCLUDE (accountAmount)` will likely be used by this query.

Comment: sure it would be used, and the index would even be more generic, but I wanted to take advantage of the percent of rows I could ignore and the reduced amount of disk space , plus personal preferences too, so I opted for the filtered index. that can be changed accordingly as to how the data is used.

Comment: If you are planning on using a filtered index just to support an aggregation query why not use an indexed view instead and precalculate the aggregation?

Comment: That's a good point and I had considered it, but on this particular situation it was an emergency and I did not have the time to proper assess the cost of having an indexed view there (IO related waits or any process that might truncate any table or whatever, I know that this database is involved in replication too) so I decided to keep it simple enough to speed things up but I might revisit it later on, as I love indexed views (within limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found on this occasion, having a look at the data, constraints, applications etc, I could change the column `notCountedInTotal` to `not null` having a default zero, as you can see on the table definition below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accountTransaction] ( 
[accountTransactionID]     INT              IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
[accountCode]              VARCHAR(30)                          NULL,
[transactionType]          CHAR(3)                              NULL,
[transactionReason]        VARCHAR(100)                         NULL,
[applicationID]            INT                                  NULL,
[invoiceID]                INT                                  NULL,
[entityID]                 INT                                  NULL,
[entityType]               CHAR(1)                              NULL,
[transactionCurrencyCode]  CHAR(3)                              NULL,
[transactionAmount]        DECIMAL(10,2)                        NULL,
[accountCurrencyCode]      CHAR(3)                              NULL,
[accountAmount]            DECIMAL(10,2)                        NULL,
[chequeNo]                 VARCHAR(20)                          NULL,
[issuingBank]              VARCHAR(50)                          NULL,
[issuingCountryCode]       CHAR(2)                              NULL,
[STReference]              VARCHAR(30)                          NULL,
[paymentMethod]            VARCHAR(10)                          NULL,
[GPStatus]                 INT                                  NULL,
[transactionDate]          DATETIME                             NULL  CONSTRAINT [DF_accountTransaction_transactionDate] DEFAULT (getdate()),
[transactionStatus]        VARCHAR(10)                          NULL,
[userID]                   INT                                  NULL,
[parentID]                 INT                                  NULL,
[transactionComment]       VARCHAR(max)                         NULL,
[notCountedInTotal]        BIT                              NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT [DF_accountTransaction_notCountedInTotal] DEFAULT ((0)),
[enteredDate]              DATETIME                             NULL  CONSTRAINT [DF_accountTransaction_enteredDate] DEFAULT (getdate()),
[chequeDetails]            VARCHAR(1000)                    NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT [DF_accountTransaction_chequeDetails] DEFAULT (''),
CONSTRAINT   [PK_accountTransaction]  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED    ([accountTransactionID] asc) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100)
```

After that it was easy to add a filtered index because there is no more the `either the value is null or the value is zero` thing.

execution plan using the newly created index:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be nice to create a computed column, persisted on notCountedInTotal column(that would put the zeros and nulls together) as below:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo.accountTransaction]    ADD [notCountedInTotal1] AS (ISNULL(notCountedInTotal,0)) PERSISTED;
```

create an index on that column as below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX F_invoiceID_notCountedInTotal1  ON dbo.accountTransaction (  INVOICEID, notCountedInTotal1 )  INCLUDE ( accountAmount)
```

Your select query would then be as simple as:

```
SELECT @amount = sum(accountAmount)  
FROM dbo.accountTransaction  
WHERE invoiceID = @invoiceID  
  AND notCountedInTotal1 = 0
```

It will utilize the index F_invoiceID_notCountedInTotal1 with index seek, query will perform very well for huge amount of data, provided the temp DB has sufficient space for aggregation.